# Problem with specific fields while querying mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, export, data-retrieval

The problem is with these two fields : `Relative Time(h:min:s.ms)` and `Real time(h:min:s.ms)`

The values cannot be retrieved While trying to export the collection to csv/json. So I tried the following:

1. full query, able to get the values for both fields.

```
> db.cell19L28A.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62be726ae6168c39e037bdd5"), "State" : "Rest", "Jump" : 1, "Cycle" : 1, "Steps" : 1, "Current(A)" : 0, "Voltage(V)" : 3.3965, "Capacity(Ah)" : 0, "Energy(Wh)" : 0, "Relative Time(h:min:s.ms)" : "0:00:00.000", "Real time(h:min:s.ms)" : "2022-07-01 09:30:46", "Process Name" : "Charge.xml", "Start Time" : "2022-07-01 09:30:46" }
```

2. able to get the values with _id = 0

```
> db.cell19L28A.find({},{"_id":0})
{ "State" : "Rest", "Jump" : 1, "Cycle" : 1, "Steps" : 1, "Current(A)" : 0, "Voltage(V)" : 3.3965, "Capacity(Ah)" : 0, "Energy(Wh)" : 0, "Relative Time(h:min:s.ms)" : "0:00:00.000", "Real time(h:min:s.ms)" : "2022-07-01 09:30:46", "Process Name" : "Charge.xml", "Start Time" : "2022-07-01 09:30:46" }
```

3. But when tried with 1 for both of those fields, an empty string is returned.

```
> db.cell19L28A.find({},{"_id":0,"Relative Time(h:min:s.ms)":1,"Real time(h:min:s.ms)":1})
{  }
{  }
{  }
```

4. able to get the values when given 0 for all the rest of the fields.

```
> db.cell19L28A.find({},{ "_id" : 0, "State" : 0, "Jump" : 0, "Cycle" : 0, "Steps" : 0, "Current(A)" : 0, "Voltage(V)" : 0, "Capacity(Ah)" : 0, "Energy(Wh)" : 0,  "Process Name" : 0, "Start Time" :0 })
{ "Relative Time(h:min:s.ms)" : "0:00:00.000", "Real time(h:min:s.ms)" : "2022-07-01 09:30:46" }
```

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the issue is with dot (`.`) in key name *`Relative Time(h:min:s.ms)`, `Real time(h:min:s.ms)`*,

There are so many [restrictions and limitations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/) if the key name contains dot (`.`), some are resolved in the latest MongoDB v5,

In your case, the projection considers it as an embedded object like this,

```
{ 
  "Relative Time(h:min:s": { 
    "ms)": 1 
  } 
}
```

because it contains a dot (`.`) in the key name, so it can't find the field and it doesn't exist.

You can use [$getField](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/#mongodb-expression-exp.-getField) from MongoDB v5.0, but it will return an object instead of your original key name,

```
db.cell19L28A.find({},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "Relative Time(h:min:s.ms)": {
    $getField: "Relative Time(h:min:s.ms)"
  },
  "Real time(h:min:s.ms)": {
    $getField: "Real time(h:min:s.ms)"
  }
})
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "Real time(h:min:s": {
      "ms)": "2022-07-01 09:30:46"
    },
    "Relative Time(h:min:s": {
      "ms)": "0:00:00.000"
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kXbQ9Ay3IkZ)

I don't see any valid solution for this, my suggestion is to avoid the dot (`.`) and dollar (`$`) in the key name.

> The values cannot be retrieved While trying to export the collection to csv/json.

There is a [warning provided in MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#general-restrictions),

> **Import and Export Concerns With Dollar Signs ($) and Periods (.)**
>
> Starting in MongoDB 5.0, document field names can be dollar (`$`) prefixed and can contain periods (`.`). However, `mongoimport` and `mongoexport` may not work as expected in some situations with field names that make use of these characters.